# Free embedded database for VBA/VB.NET billing desktop application

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, vba, embedded-database

This is mt first post, so any mistakes pls excuse.

I have created a excel based billing system using forms and  VBA. Basically when i open the excel file and select the customer name, his details are pre-loaded from excel into the forma and once bill details are entered, the bill is generate and amount details are stored in excel with bill number and a pdf is generated. All works fine.

But, now I am planning to create my own desktop application to replicate the same behavior instead of sharing an excel file to my customers.

So please suggest me where to start and which database should I use. I dont want a server-client database model as my customers dont have any IT department to maintain a database, all they will do is they will just click the exe file i give and start using the application.

I have so far created the form using visual basic.net

Please guide me.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Sqlite, without any doubt